# Azure devops Release pipeline - Artifacts download being skipped for specific agent why?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release pipeline that deploys to two different Agents. Both stages has "Run on Agent" job and has same "Task group" item added to the both. When running I see "Skipping artifact download based on the setting specified." in the logs of "Initialize Job" for only one Agent and not on the other. Why download is skipped in only one Agent Job?  Note: The setting "Skip download Artifacts" is Unchecked in both Agent jobs.
[image]

Comment: 1. Please add a variable named `system.debug` and set the value to `true`, after that create a new release. Then check the debug log of the Initialize job task in **each** stage. Please search for `RELEASE_SKIPARTIFACTSDOWNLOAD` and check the value of it. 2. Please add a new stage, run on the agent which skipped the artifact before and add only a default "Command line" task, then create a new release. Please check whether the artifact is downloaded or not.